# Linq query & generics

Tags: c#, sql, linq, generics

I have about 3 classes, `Author`, `Book` & `Library`. I have the following function which makes use of generics to query the DB for all records:

```
public static System.ComponentModel.BindingList<T> getRecordsOfType<T>() where T : class, IEntity
{
    var records = session.Query.All<T>();
    return new System.ComponentModel.BindingList<T>(records.ToList<T>());
}
```

This works fine, now my following function should get one record using its Id:

```
public static System.ComponentModel.BindingList<T> getRecordOfTypeById<T>(int intId) where T : class, IEntity
{
    var record = session.Query.All<T>().Where(p => p.Id == intId);
    return new System.ComponentModel.BindingList<T>(record.ToList<T>());
}
```

Here C# doesn't know that p will have the property Id (which all my classes have that will be using this function) because I'm using generics.

Of course I could iterate through Library, Book and Author and write a different query for each, but if I want to expand I'll have  write extra code in this function.

Can this be solved using Linq, or will I need to work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IEntity should contain property called Id and it will work, or you can make other interface IHaveId for e.g.

```
public static System.ComponentModel.BindingList<T> 
              getRecordOfTypeById<T>(int intId) where T : class, IEntity, IHaveId
```

and interface like:

```
public interface IHaveId
{
    int Id { get; set;}
}
```

All of entities used in this method should implement `IHaveId` interface

If you do all above you will be sure that `p` will have `Id` and you will be able to use it in generic method.

Comment: Wow, awesome works perfectly! IEntity didn't have Id, but I just made a new interface like you said, pretty new to generics so didn't know it worked like this. Thanks!

Comment: +1 perfectly put, exactly as i would have suggested. The power of interfaces and generics is quite awesome